# Global variable returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, so pardon me my trivial mistakes. I have written the following script in which `res` is supposed to be a Global variable in the script file. I am setting the global `res` in a method and then accessing it in another method, however the issue is, `this.issue` returns `undefined` in method Y but it isn't undefined in the method X where I assign a value to it. Why is that?

**Method X is called before Method Y.**

```
var res;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', shortenedUrl: ''});
});


router.X('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    this.res = res;
    console.log("this.res: "+ this.res); // this.res not undefined here
    Y();
});

function Y(){
    console.log("this.res: "+ this.res); // this.res here becomes undefined
});
```

Comment: because `this` is different in both cases

Comment: read [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) about Closures

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with what we call scope. `this` inside a function is related to the specific scope of that function, thus, `this.res` in your case is always local to the functions where you are using it.

The correct way to access the global `res` would be to only use `res`, but you have another conflict that comes from the function argument with the same name.

I would suggest:

```
var res;

router.X('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, _res, next) {
    res = _res;
    console.log("res: ", res);
    Y();
});

function Y(){
    console.log("res: ", res); // res will now have the correct value
});
```

**P.S.:** Also use `,` instead of `+` on console logs, so that the console outputs the full object tree.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in Javascript is that global variables can not be set inside functions with **this**. In your case the variable returns undefined because **res** was not definded outside the functions. 
To solve this problem you can use

> window.res

That means in your code:

```
var res;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  window.res.render('index', { title: 'Express', shortenedUrl: ''});
});


router.X('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    window.res = res;
    console.log("this.res: "+ this.res);
    Y();
});

function Y(){
    console.log("this.res: "+ window.res); // it becomes no longer undefined
});
```

PS: It may be possible that I wrongly interpretet your code but I hope it will help you fixing your problem ;)